# Создание таблицы в android

Tags: android

Всем привет! Скажите пожалуйста с помощью чего делают такие таблицы которые реагируют на нажитие строк и столбцов???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)
Посмотри здесь пример:
http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/gridview.php

Comment: Ок. Спасибо, посмотрю

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо.